# iOS - ambiguous layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, storyboard, ios-autolayout

So i am trying lo locate a UIlabel in 2 conditions:
1.portrait 
2.landscape

As far as i know i am doing as i should with vary for traits.

i can see the label in the storyboard located as i wanted:

[image]
[image]

yet in the iphone it doesn't appears in the landscape mode:

[image]
[image]

in the debugview tool i can see on the label - uilabel has ambiguous layout:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Is this what stops the uilabel from being shown? 
and if so what i should do?

Comment: With your label selected in the view debugging hierarchy, choose the Size Inspector view.  It should show you the constraints that are being applied to that object.

Comment: @PhillipMills it shows that the height is 0,
i will add this too the answer.

Comment: Does it also show the constraints that are in effect?

Comment: @PhillipMills just updated the answer, is that fully detailed(you can see that the height is affected)

Comment: @ironRoei - if you're still trying to fix this, can you post your storyboard's source (no need for any of the code)? It *looks* like you've done what you need for trait variations, but it would be much easier to try to help if we could see the actual storyboard.

Comment: @DonMag, sure!!
i have updated my question and added the storyboard , is that good?

Comment: @ironRoei - sorry, no... I meant: right-click on your storyboard and select `Open As -> Source Code`. That will show the xml used to define the storyboard, and I can copy/paste it to double-check your constraints setup.

Comment: @DonMag sure, want to open a conversation and i will send you that?

Comment: @ironRoei - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190367/room-for-donmag-and-ironroei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few hours i have managed to fix it.
The VC inherits from a base VC and in the base VC i also creates a label hardcoded.
As you can see there are 2 UIlabels with the same text.
What i did was to exclude the VC above so  the label wont build in the base.